# Heavy processing inside loop - How to optimize?

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PHP and English is not my mother toungue, so sorry in advance!

I am creating a PHP (5.6) script that will be called by a cronjob everyday at 3am and remove all user's data (database and files) when their license expires. It's about 10 different MySQL tables and 400 MB of files and folders.

Here is a simple example (pseudo code) on how it works today:

```
Select all users whose license expired

  While not end of list do

    Remove all files and folders from user i

    Delete all data from table1 where user = i

    Delete all data from table2 where user = i

    ...

    Delete all data from table10 where user = i

    Update data from tableUsers where user = i

  End While

End Select
```

There will be maybe 10-20 users to process data everyday, so I am looking for a way to optimize this task. Is there any good practices or advices for this kind of processing? For example, list the users into an array, free the query results and loop the array would make any difference?

**PS.** This is a theoretical question, I do not need code, only ideas. So I can research more using new keywords.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some tips for working with many users and a database is that your can use the where `IN` clause, documentation found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in). Essentially, you can find all the user id's of what to delete, and use the `'WHERE IN(' . implode( ',', $arrayOfUserIds ) . ')'`

This should cut down the amount of database queries required to call for each loop.

Comment: This is indeed a good idea to optimize, thanks! But let me wait for more ideas...

Answer (score 0):

Add a foreign key referencing user from table 1..10 to tableusers with cascade update at delete.
This way, if you delete the user from tableusers, it will be automatically deleted from table 1..10.

Also, delete all files and folders for all users whose license expired, then run:

```
delete from tableusers where user in (Select all users whose license expired subquery);
```

This way, it will delete all users whose license expired in a single query.

Comment: Never heard about this approach, I will research about it. Thank you!